# Memurai Developer Setup Wizard ended prematurely

Tags: windows, redis, memurai

I'm trying to install `Redis` through `MEMURAI` but when I run the setup I get the following error:

[image]

I've `Windows 10 - BUILD: 1909`

The latest .NET version, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some steps that will help investigate this issue:

1. From an Administrator command prompt, navigate to the folder where the Memurai Developer installer is located (typically it's under %userprofile%\downloads). EG: `cd /d %userprofile%\downloads`
2. `msiexec /i Memurai-Developer-2.0.0.msi /l*v "install.log"`.
3. Proceed through the installer steps as you did before, until you hit the error.

The `install.log` file should provide some clue as to why the installation failed. If the solution is not obvious, please email the log file to support@memurai.com. Please let us know how it goes, either way!

Note: After the install logs were investigated the installer was changed to make it more robust and not fail in this spot.

Comment: I did what you suggested and sended the `install.log` via email, could you please take a look? Thanks